# Not able to implement chaincode on peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': chaincode already successfully installed (package ID 'mychaincode_1.0:39889cf0623cce2500261b22914a7aa9037a897bc7f6c5b36df7a922f29b05e0').

Throwing this error. Telling Successfully installed but not implementing on peers. What to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the chaincode is already installed, it may be that you need to increment the sequence number when trying to install a newer version. If you install the contract from the command line, you may need to increment these values by one

export CC_PACKAGE_VERSION=1

export CC_PACKAGE_SEQUENCE=1

If you are using the deployCC.sh script to install the contract, you should increment the sequence number either on the parameter list when running the script, or else make the change internally by incrementing the following variables which take the parameter values if supplied

CC_VERSION=${5:-"1.0"}

CC_SEQUENCE=${6:-"1"}

... change to

CC_VERSION=${5:-"2"}

CC_SEQUENCE=${6:-"2"}

This is my first suspicion as to the reason why your code will not install. If this doesn't help, have a look at the docker logs for the peer to see if there are any hints.